# Jasypt encrypt and check password not working

Tags: java, encryption, jasypt

I have a problem with jasypt. It encrypts the password correctly, but if I try to check password it hangs and never comes out.

Any tip could help, thanks.

I'm working with tomcat 8. It does not work. Could it be a security issue?

```
public class CryptoLogica {

    public boolean validarPass(UsuarioDTO u,String pass) {
        //traer pass encrptado de bd
        StrongPasswordEncryptor passwordEncryptor = new StrongPasswordEncryptor();
        return passwordEncryptor.checkPassword(pass, u.getPass());
    }

    public String encriptarPass(String pass) {
        StrongPasswordEncryptor passwordEncryptor = new StrongPasswordEncryptor();
        return passwordEncryptor.encryptPassword(pass);
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure u.getPass is not where the problem is?  I'd pull that result into a separate variable, then pass it to the checkPassword method.

Comment: Also, how does it store the SALT?

Comment: I found the problem. i'm using two projects that use jasypt and one of them was missing the import of jasypt. the error was weird, and did not point to the cause. Thanks